# Splitting a video into pieces

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

I am trying to split a video in to different  sections and have them saved in a array. I found this code, but when I run it I get: type error: 'none type' object is not subscriptable. I can't see anything wrong in the code.

I got the code working
Fixed code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Test_5_vid.MP4')
n_rows = 3
n_images_per_row = 3

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret: #this is what needed to be added 
        print('not working')
        break
    
    height = 1080
    width = 1080

    roi_height = int(height / n_rows)
    roi_width = int(width / n_images_per_row)

    images = []

    for x in range(0, n_rows):
        for y in range(0,n_images_per_row):
            tmp_image=frame[x*roi_height:(x+1)*roi_height, y*roi_width:(y+1)*roi_width]
            images.append(tmp_image)
           
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: There seems to have something gone wrong with the indentation, could you please fix it first?

Comment: Next, could you please tell us in which line the error occurs?

Comment: As @mkrieger1 stated, it is difficult for us to assist you if you do not post the full crash error. In general, the context surround an error provides highly valuable information about what specifically went wrong.

Comment: Have you wondered already what `ret` is good for?

Comment: The common assumption that `cap.read()` can never fail (even when it reaches the end of the video) and thus not bothering to check for failures and handle them properly. Well, it failed, `frame` is `None`, and you're trying to index it (call its operator []), which doesn't make sense for `None`.

Comment: "I found this code" -- internet is full of crappy code examples. Anything you find, you need to scrutinize, and make sure you understand what exactly it's doing and why. People mindlessly copying and spreading that nonsense is a big part of the problem.

Comment: So is the problem that ```cap.read()``` is giving ```ret``` no frames so returns ```None```? when I run the program I can see that ```ret``` is getting the value ```True```, in till the video is done

Comment: Why do you have both duplicate looping? You can merely used one looping.

Comment: @SophiaTatarek Great! Can you post your solution as an **answer** to your original question, then accept it? So, the question would have the original (non-working) code, and the answer would show the fixed version separately. This helps other people with the same question find the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer